# Magento 2.2.2 remove other shipping methods and enable only free shipping if consumer total more than 100

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shipping-methods, magento2.2.2

We are using **Magento 2.2.2**, We have more then 5 shipping methods enabled in our site.

We needs to remove other shipping methods and enable only free shipping if the cost of their order totals to more then 100.

And if it totals less then 100 then all other shipping methods will enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove Flat Rate when subtotal is more than 100, you can add below code.

**vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php**

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request){
    ....

    // Add this code
    if($request->getSubtotalIncludingTax() > 100){
         return false;
    }
    // Code End

    ...
}
```

Also set subtotal including tax value in request of below function

**vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php**

```
public function requestShippingRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item = null)
{
    ...

    $validateFreeShippingTotal = $this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $this->getBaseTaxAmount();
    $request->setSubtotalIncludingTax($validateFreeShippingTotal);

    ...
}
```

Comment: never edit VENDOR files!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by overriding the

> \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::getShippingMethods function.

```
private function getShippingMethods(Quote $quote, $address)
{
    $output = [];
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->addData($this->extractAddressData($address));
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);

    $this->totalsCollector->collectAddressTotals($quote, $shippingAddress);
    $shippingRates = $shippingAddress->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
    foreach ($shippingRates as $carrierRates) {
        foreach ($carrierRates as $rate) {
            $output[] = $this->converter->modelToDataObject($rate, $quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

This method is responsible for providing all the available shipping methods. So all you have to do is, check the grand total of the quote and enable the respective methods.

Below are the modified lines to display only free shipping when order amount goes above 100.

```
foreach ($shippingRates as $carrierRates) {
    foreach ($carrierRates as $rate) {
        if ($quote->getGrandTotal() <= 100) {
            $output[] = $this->converter->modelToDataObject($rate, $quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
        } else {
            if ($rate->getMethod() == "freeshipping") {
                $output[] = $this->converter->modelToDataObject($rate, $quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Since this method is a private function, you can't use plugins. You can go with preference to achieve that.

Comment: How can I get the customer?

Comment: @Mike We can't overridden   `getShippingMethods` as it's private function

Comment: @MahendraJella you are right. i am not able to override this method. can you tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @Ravindrasinh is half the answer: it explains how you can show a shipping method from a given amount. Your question is also about the inverse of this: hide certain shipping methods from a given amount.

What you need to do is write plugins after the `collectRates()`-methods of the given shipping methods so you can manipulate the outcome according to your own quote.

Answer (score 2):

Now check screen short for apply free shipping and other shipping method Flat rate , table rate option in `No` then all are disable only free shipping enable `Yes`

> Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Method -> Free Shipping

[image]

Free shipping cart image

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your are saying, can you please explain me in detail ? please check my updated question for more information

Comment: In your screenshot there is only freeshipping method

Comment: yes only free shipping enable and other shipping method disable

Comment: which type of issue are face

Comment: but in my case more then 5 shipping methods are enabled

Comment: simple only free shipping enable and other method disable so problem slove

Comment: I'm not facing any issue, I need conditional shipping method, like if total more then 100 then other methods will disable and only freeshipping method is showing in shipping block, and less then 100 then all shipping methods will show.

Answer (score 1):

Write a plugin to disable flat rate shipping method when free shipping is actually enabled based on cart sub total.

1-> Create custom module `Hello_World`

2-> Create plugin and configure in `di.xml` file, `app/code/Hello/World/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate">
        <plugin name="disable-flatrate" type="Hello\World\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Write a Model class to process sub total validation.

3-> Create model file `app/code/Hello/World/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php`

```
<?php
namespace Hello\World\Model\Carrier;

class Flatrate
{

    const XML_PATH_FREE_SHIPPING_SUBTOTAL = "carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal";

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $flatRate, $result)
    {
        $scopeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;

        // Get MOA value from system configuration.
        $freeShippingSubTotal = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_FREE_SHIPPING_SUBTOTAL, $storeScope, $scopeId);

        // Get cart subtotal from checkout session.
        $baseSubTotal = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getBaseSubtotal();

        // Validate subtoal should be empty or Zero.
        if(!empty($baseSubTotal) && !empty($freeShippingSubTotal)) {

            if($baseSubTotal >= $freeShippingSubTotal) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove Flat Rate when subtotal is more than 1000, you can add below code.

****vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php****

$request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() <= 1000