# Remove flat rate handling fee on orders above 1000

Tags: magento2, discount, delivery

How can i remove flat rate handling fee if the order is above $1000 ?I cant do it with a rule, as it still shows as if some discount was applied.I need to remove the handling fee itself.

Thanks for Advance!

Comment: Please specify Magento version

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways

1) create free shipping method in admin side like check this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212397/55928

2) if you don't want to create another method and continue with flat rate and just remove charges follow this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212409/55928